# pyspark.ml: Type error when computing precision and recall

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I am trying to compute precision, recall and F1 for a classifier, using `pyspark.ml`:

```
model = completePipeline.fit(training)
predictions = model.transform(test)

mm = MulticlassMetrics(predictions.select(["label", "prediction"]).rdd)


labels = sorted(predictions.select("prediction").rdd.distinct().map(lambda r: r[0]).collect())

for label in labels:
    print labels
    print "Precision = %s" % mm.precision(label=label) 
    print "Recall = %s" % mm.recall(label=label) 
    print "F1 Score = %s" % mm.fMeasure(label=label)

metrics = pandas.DataFrame([(label, mm.precision(label=label), mm.recall(label=label), mm.fMeasure(label=label)) for label in labels],
                            columns=["Precision", "Recall", "F1"])
```

The schema of the resulting data frame `predictions`:

```
[('features', 'vector'), ('label', 'int'), ('rawPrediction', 'vector'), ('probability', 'vector'), ('prediction', 'double')]
```

The error message triggered by the call to `mm.precision`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ml_pipeline_factory_test", line 1, in <module>
  File "ml_pipeline_factory_test", line 92, in ml_pipeline_factory_test
  File "/tmp/conda-9a013169-8b21-43cb-bcbe-06fc31523d3e/real/envs/conda-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/mllib/evaluation.py", line 240, in precision
    return self.call("precision", float(label))
  File "/tmp/conda-9a013169-8b21-43cb-bcbe-06fc31523d3e/real/envs/conda-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/mllib/common.py", line 146, in call
    return callJavaFunc(self._sc, getattr(self._java_model, name), *a)
  File "/tmp/conda-9a013169-8b21-43cb-bcbe-06fc31523d3e/real/envs/conda-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/mllib/common.py", line 123, in callJavaFunc
    return _java2py(sc, func(*args))
  File "/tmp/conda-9a013169-8b21-43cb-bcbe-06fc31523d3e/real/envs/conda-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1160, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/tmp/conda-9a013169-8b21-43cb-bcbe-06fc31523d3e/real/envs/conda-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/tmp/conda-9a013169-8b21-43cb-bcbe-06fc31523d3e/real/envs/conda-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 320, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o371.precision.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 7 in stage 22.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 7.3 in stage 22.0 (TID 153, dhbpdn12.de.t-internal.com, executor 4): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/conda-e6ac7105-4788-4b4c-9163-ba8763f29ead/real/envs/conda-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/worker.py", line 245, in main
    process()
  File "/tmp/conda-e6ac7105-4788-4b4c-9163-ba8763f29ead/real/envs/conda-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/worker.py", line 240, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/tmp/conda-e6ac7105-4788-4b4c-9163-ba8763f29ead/real/envs/conda-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/serializers.py", line 372, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/tmp/conda-9a013169-8b21-43cb-bcbe-06fc31523d3e/real/envs/conda-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 677, in prepare
  File "/tmp/conda-9a013169-8b21-43cb-bcbe-06fc31523d3e/real/envs/conda-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1421, in verify
  File "/tmp/conda-9a013169-8b21-43cb-bcbe-06fc31523d3e/real/envs/conda-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1402, in verify_struct
  File "/tmp/conda-9a013169-8b21-43cb-bcbe-06fc31523d3e/real/envs/conda-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1421, in verify
  File "/tmp/conda-9a013169-8b21-43cb-bcbe-06fc31523d3e/real/envs/conda-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1415, in verify_default
  File "/tmp/conda-9a013169-8b21-43cb-bcbe-06fc31523d3e/real/envs/conda-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1310, in verify_acceptable_types
TypeError: field prediction: DoubleType can not accept object 0 in type <type 'int'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the error message:

> ```
> TypeError: field prediction: DoubleType can not accept object 0 in type <type 'int'>
> ```

type matter. While `int` and `float` are generally exchangeable in Python, there are not in Java.

The simplest solution is to cast `label` field upstream:

```
predictions = (predictions
    .withColumn("label", predictions["label"].cast("double")))
```

Comment: The problem is "label" (`('label', 'int')`) not "prediction". Please check if edit helps

Comment: Yes, that fixed the type error, thanks. Is it just me or is it weird that evaluation for a **classifier** expects labels to be of type double?

Comment: It is, but it is standard Spark behavior. It is all about simplicity of implementation. Original `mllib` API uses `LabeledPoint` for both classification and regression models. That's why `Double` has been used there. Also all low level libraries used under the cover operate on FP numbers and don't support integers.

Comment: The same thing will happen there (there is always some Blas out there, and it doesn't support integers), it is just transpartent.